# Recursion: computing $f(3^{100})$

Tags: contest-math, recursion

Given the function $f:N^+ \rightarrow N$ such that: $f(2^n)=n^2$, $f(3n)=f(2n)+5$, Find the value of $f(3^{100})$:

I tried calculating some smaller $f(3^k)$ for integer $k$, to look for a pattern, If I haven't done silly mistakes I got:$$f(3)=6,f(3^2)=9,f(3^3)=24,f(3^4)=36$$
I noticed that $f(3)\cdot4=f(3^3)$ and $f(3^2)\cdot4=f(3^4)$, nonetheless, I don't think this kind of pattern holds, I wrote in general that: $$f(3\cdot2^n)=n^2+2n+6$$
Hints or partial help is much appreciated!

Comment: Let me know if I made some silly mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily show by induction that for all $n \in \lbrace 0, ..., 100 \rbrace$, 
$$f(3^{100})=f(2^n \times 3^{100-n}) + 5n$$

Using that with $n=100$, you get
$$f(3^{100}) = f(2^{100}) + 500 = 100^2+ 500 = 10500$$

Comment: $f(3^{100})=f(3.3^{99})=f(2.3^{99})+5 = f(3.(2.3^{98}))+5 = f(2.2.3^{98}) + 5+5 = f(2^2.3^{98})+2\times5 = ...$ and so on.

Comment: Right! I had deleted my comment because I was trying exactly that! great, thanks